# glGenTextures(1,&texture)関数を使うと画面が真っ白になる原因が知りたい。

Tags: c++, opengl

提示コードの`glGenTextures()`関数部ですがこの関数を実行すると画面が真っ白になるのですがこれは何が原因なのでしょうか？

参考サイト: http://wisdom.sakura.ne.jp/system/opengl/gl23.html

###### 試したこと

この関数をコメントアウトすると正常に実行できモデルが描画されるためこの関数が原因なのは確実です。
`texture`変数を`printf()`すると１が返ってきます。

```cpp
// ##################################### キューブマップテクスチャ 生成 ##################################### 
GLuint FrameWork::LoadTexture_CubeMap(std::vector<std::string> filePath)
{
    
    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);            //テクスチャIDの生成
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture); // IDバインド
    
    for (int i = 0; i < filePath.size(); i++)
    {
        glm::ivec2 size;
        int channel;

        unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filePath.at(i).c_str(),&size.x,&size.y,&channel,0);
 
        if (data != NULL)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, size.x, size.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);          
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Cubemap texture failed to load at path: " << filePath.at(i) << std::endl;
            assert(0);
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
    }
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    
    return texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

フレームバッファを利用しているプロジェクトなのですがカスタムフレームバッファを作成する前にglGenTexture()関数を使っているためでした。